# Deleting of firebase real-time database is not working in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

trying to delete firebase realtime database key where data is equal to. please see my database

[image]

I want remove the data where pickupid equal to `4215`

I tried below code

```
var RestoId = document.getElementById('RestoId').value;
      const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child(RestoId);

      dbRefObject.orderByChild('pickupid').equalTo(6744)
      .on('child_added',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.key.set(null);

        //console.log(snapshot.key);

      });
```

how to remove data from firebase realtime database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref("Resto_1");

  dbRefObject.orderByChild('pickupid').equalTo(4215)
  .once('value',(snapshot)=> {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=> {
     let nodeKey = childSnapshot.key;
     firebase.database().ref("Resto_1").child(nodeKey).remove();
  });
```

This will remove the node `-Lnx4WH3arUC5wH3b1QU` and all the data inside of it.

Check the docs for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#remove

Comment: this removed all the data of Resto_1. i want to remove equal to 4215 with key pickupid